# How to translate timestamp in miliseconds to time?

Tags: perl

How do I translate a timestamp in miliseconds to a time format like "13:52:11.12"?

Comment: What format is the timestamp? Is it perhaps [epoch seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number)?

Comment: Do you want a duration? For example "125" are 2 minutes and 5 seconds. Or do you want a date from an epoch time. 125 for example is the date `Thu Jan  1 01:02:05 1970`.

Answer (score 5):

```
use DateTime;
my $t = time() * 1000 + 400;

print DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $t/1000)->format_cldr('H:m:s.S');
# 13:22:47.4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
divide by 1000 to get seconds.
Divide by 86400 to get days
Divide remainder of above division by 3600 to get hours
Divide remainder by 60 to get minutes, remainder is seconds
```

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours. Not all minutes have 60 seconds (although I think epoch time doesn't include 61th seconds).